# SQL IF EXIST in a script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, jython-2.5

I'f this is in the wrong area, kindly direct me to the right area
I'm working with Ignition BY inductiveautomation, and trying to write a script that will update or insert based on the IF EXIST condition.
I have a query that will insert a new record into my DB listed below, but now I want to be able to update the "setupsheet" if it already exist.

```
Code:
queryValue1 = event.source.parent.getComponent('MoldName').selectedStringValue
queryValue2 = event.source.parent.getComponent('MachineName').selectedStringValue
queryValue3 = event.source.parent.getComponent('Text Area').text
if system.gui.confirm("Steve! Are you sure you want to Save changes?", 
   "Save Changes"):      
      system.db.runPrepUpdate("INSERT INTO setup_sheetlist (MoldName,machineName,Setupsheet) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')" % (queryValue1, queryValue2 , queryValue3), getKey=1)
```

This is my query, its working in my DB but I'm a lost on how to implement it into the RunPrepUpdate,

```
    Code:
    IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM setup_sheetlist WHERE moldname='100SCX-3' AND Machinename='MM11')
       UPDATE setup_sheetlist 
       SET  setupsheet ='updated value 3'
       WHERE moldname='100SCX-3' AND Machinename='MM11'

    ELSE
           INSERT INTO setup_sheetlist(MoldName,machineName,Setupsheet)
           VALUES('100SCX-3','MM11','TRIAL 2')
```

This is what I have so far, this gives me an error message

```
    queryValue1 = event.source.parent.getComponent('MoldName').selectedStringValue
queryValue2 = event.source.parent.getComponent('MachineName').selectedStringValue
queryValue3 = event.source.parent.getComponent('Text Area').text
if system.gui.confirm("Steve! Are you sure you want to Save changes?", 
    "Save Changes"):        

            system.db.runPrepUpdate("IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM setup_sheetlist WHERE moldname='?' AND Machinename='?')UPDATE setup_sheetlist SET  setupsheet ='?'    WHERE moldname='?' AND Machinename='?'" ,[queryValue1,queryValue2,queryValue3,queryValue1,queryValue2] )
            ELSE 
            INSERT 
            INTO 
            setup_sheetlist (MoldName,machineName,Setupsheet)
            VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')" % (queryValue1, queryValue2 , queryValue3))
```

Error

```
Error: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.Exception: Error executing system.db.runPrepUpdate(IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM setup_sheetlist WHERE moldname='?' AND Machinename='?')UPDATE setup_sheetlist       SET  setupsheet ='updated value 3'   WHERE moldname='?' AND Machinename='?', [100SCX-3, MM09, 100SCX-3, MM09], , , false, false)


   caused by Exception: Error executing system.db.runPrepUpdate(IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM setup_sheetlist WHERE moldname='?' AND Machinename='?')UPDATE setup_sheetlist       SET  setupsheet ='updated value 3'   WHERE moldname='?' AND Machinename='?', [100SCX-3, MM09, 100SCX-3, MM09], , , false, false)
   caused by GatewayException: SQL error for "IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM setup_sheetlist WHERE moldname='?' AND Machinename='?')UPDATE setup_sheetlist       SET  setupsheet ='updated value 3'   WHERE moldname='?' AND Machinename='?'": The index 1 is out of range.
   caused by SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of range.
```

Full Error report http://pastebin.com/d7Jt7fcr

Comment: I suspect that you are not getting any values for queryValue1 & queryValue2.   Can you run print statements to verify what's in those variables right before the runPrepUpdate?

Comment: @TabAlleman, The query value1&2 worked with the insert statement before I added the if exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have passed the variable all at once at the end of the query instead of breaking it to parts.

```
  system.db.runPrepUpdate("IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM setup_sheetlist WHERE moldname=? AND Machinename=?)UPDATE setup_sheetlist SET setupsheet =? WHERE moldname=? AND Machinename=? ELSE INSERT INTO setup_sheetlist (MoldName,machineName,Setupsheet) VALUES (?,?,?)" , (queryValue1,queryValue2,queryValue3,queryValue1,queryValue2,queryValue1, queryValue2 , queryValue3 ))
```